# How do I show (collection) associations in Visual Studio's generated class diagrams?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, stl, class-diagram, model-associations

Visual studio doesn't seem to recognize c++ STL classes properly when it comes to generating class diagrams.

There are two options when right-clicking class elements in the generated diagrams:
    - Show as Association
    - Show as Collection Association

I would like to use both, but I use `std::shared_ptr`, `std::vector`, `std::map` and such, which Visual Studio won't recognize.

Is there an add-in I don't know about or another program that does a better job at reverse engineering existing classes to UML Class Diagrams?